# Inspector show 3 sec update, how do I get newly value?

Tags: java, php, html, json, ajax

In index.php I have a javasript, that take JSON data from data.php every 3 sec. Data.php end with this:

> echo json_encode($row);

Inspector in index.php shows a couple of objects (which are refreshed each 3 sec). Say 3 rows in DB, then it will look like this:

> =>[Object, Object, Object]

I can open the above, and it looks like this:

> 0: Object
>     1: Object
>     2: Object

Each three can be opened again I see my newly updated data (if it change in data.php).

How do I pull out information from those objects, so I can use it live on index.php?

I should probably add the javascript that import data as well:

```
    function populate(){
       var items= [];
       $.ajax({
       url: 'data.php',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',

       success: function(data){

          console.log(data);  

          $.each(data, function(i,v){
          items.push('< th >'+v+'< /th >');
          });       

          $('#sampleTable').html(items.join(','));
      },
      error: function(err){
          console.log(err.responseText);
      }
   });
   }

   setInterval(function(){
      populate();
   },3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(object_to_parse);
```

and then use associative names like if it is from db and there is column name `id` then you get it by `obj.id` and so on

maybe then

```
for(var i=0;i<response_data.length;i++)
{
  obj = JSON.parse(response_data[i]);
  var new_li = $('<li/>',{ 'text':obj.id });
  $('#parrent_id').append(new_li);
}
```

Comment: thanks for feedback, but how do I get that into html, say split up the different data. Imagine the data from `$row[0]['id'] $row[1]['id'] $row[2]['id']` into `<li>1 </li> <li>2 </li> <li>3 </li>` ?

Comment: how is your data structured? is those three objects like database rows? and do you need one row in list and is this list premade or you need to make it with jquery?

Comment: Yeah  I guess so. I get a refresh every 3 second, that means a new line of objects in inspector. I need a specific type of data in list, I edited my comment above

Comment: Ty, but still have problems pulling out the data. I am pretty new in java/ajax, so I dont really know how to put it inside html lists. Possible you can show a simple html example ?

Comment: @HansPede can you please give me example data from php before you json_encode_it and sample of html page where to put data in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116844/discussion-between-edgars-aivars-and-hans-pede).